# Symbol table not found Python using f2py

Tags: python, module, f2py

I am trying to generate a modulo in python from a fortran subroutine using F2py.

I use the following code in the CMD:

```
f2py -c -m fib1 fib1.f --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32
```

So it should create a python module but it returns me the following error:

```
valueError: symbol table not found
```

I installed everything alright in the MingW as compiler, so I have no idea what I am supposed to do now. I clipped the CMD output:

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "fib1" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7\fib1module.c
creating c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7
Reading fortran codes...
    Reading file 'fib1.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
    Block: fib1
            Block: fib
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
    Building module "fib1"...
        Constructing wrapper function "fib"...
          a = fib(n)
    Wrote C/API module "fib1" to file "c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7\fib1module.c"
  adding 'c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\pmacha~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpdzho8n\src.win-amd64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Looking for python27.dll
Building import library (arch=AMD64): "C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\libs\libpython27.a" (from C:\Users\pmachado3\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python27.dll)
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Can you run the command with `--verbose` and post the complete output.?

Comment: @AshSharma its not recognized as command here

Comment: `f2py -c -m fib1 fib1.f --verbose --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32` what is the error that it produces when you key this in.?

Comment: This is an option under f2py and it should work.